# How to download mp3 file with custom name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, html5-audio

I want to download mp3 file with custom name.
I've already tried download attr but no success.

Example:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/testing.mp3" download="abcd.mp3">Download</a>
```

I just want to download testing.mp3 file with the name of abcd.mp3.

Comment: there's no JS here. just some html...

Comment: yes, I know But I've added because I need to know that Is there any javascript, jquery or angularjs function to do this sort of things.

Answer (score 1):

Try not giving the mp3 extension in the download attribute's value.

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/testing.mp3" download="abcd">Download</a>
```

Please, check the browser support for *download* attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

Comment: Tested, on images its working, but on mp3 files I'm not getting the value specified in the download attribute as the file name...

Comment: Not working on mp3 files. It's downloading with the same name like testing.mp3

Comment: It's working correctly for me on FF and Chrome. Could you please make sure that you are not using IE or Safari, as they don't support _download_ attribute.

Comment: @AnkitSaroch, I've tried both browsers FF and chrome. both are downloading with the same name. Is there any other way to get this done ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084567/c-sharp-dynamically-rename-file-upon-download-request#answer-3084600